# print *.idw draw (autodesk inventor) from windows with the right paper size and orientation

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, explorer

I need to print a lot of files *.idw from windows. The formats A3 (landscape) and A4 (portrait) will be send to a basic printer and all the other formats will be send to a plotter (landscape).
I wrote a VBA code to use in Inventor that works well, for each draw open, but the idea is to finish all the draws and then, in de windows folder, send them all to printer with the good paper size and orientation.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: The software is Autodesk Inventor, a CAD software. When I click Print on the right-click button of the mouse that's opens Inventor (if not opened) and print directely the draw file (*.idw) but it won't set paper size nor orientation. And I don't know how to pass those settings...

Comment: I (and probably most users here) have no idea about your software, so please give us something to start with. As a start for you: in a batchfile use `for %%a in (*.idw) do echo %%a` to get all idw files. Instead of `echo`, I'd suggest calling an application which is able to print with proper parameters (we can assist with proper formatting of the parameters, but we don't know, which application you use to print and what parameters it uses - providing this information will be your part)

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks. See edit, please.